# Can you make an object in Javascript which does NOT inherit from Object?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, object

Occasionally there is a JS [framework](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Array) or library that thinks it's a really wise idea to add some net new features to the prototype of `Object` or `Array`. I can't find any more examples right now, but I do remember that I've had problems with that before. Of course, doing so breaks the good old `for(...in...)` loop, because suddenly those properties are now enumerated too. To get around it you have to check every enumerated property with `.hasOwnProperty()` before accessing. Which is cumbersome, when trying to write robust code.

So I got wondering - is there some way that I could make my own objects so, that they don't inherit from `Object`? Initial playing around with `.prototype` yielded no results. Perhaps there is some trick to it? Or will everything always inherit from `Object` and there's nothing I can do about it?

**Added:** I guess I should have noted that I want it for client-scripts in browsers, and compatibility should include IE6, or at least IE7. Other browser version requirements are more lenient, though the more the better, of course. (Yes, sadly, the corporate world still lives in IE-world...)

Comment: *bad* old `for(...in...)` loop surely

Comment: @RobAgar - why so? Really, I'm tired of writing stuff like `for (var i, l = myArray.length; i < l; i++)`. I long for the reliable "foreach" construct that is a de-facto standard in almost all contemporary languages.

Comment: usually the frameworks that change the prototype, also provide a way to loop through the elements. In Mootools, `myObj.each()` will do the work.. also `["foo","bar"].each()`

Comment: because `for...in` doesn't differentiate between function and non-function properties, which is rarely what I want. For my money, iterators like Mootools `each()` provide a better `foreach` equivalent.

Comment: I thought maybe overriding propertyIsEnumerable could work, but I tried it and browser doesn't seem to accept my modified version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ECMAScript 5 you can pass `null` to [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
> obj = Object.create(null);
  Object
    No Properties
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome! It actually works! Except the browser compatibility is dismal. :( I guess I should have said that I need it for IE6, or at least IE7.

Comment: I think in that case you are out of luck and using `.hasOwnProperty` is your only chance.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly remove any Object properties that are enumerable,
but moderen browsers allow nonenumerable Object methods.

Should work in older browsers though.

```
function Myobject(props){
}
var O=Object,OP=Object.prototype;
for(var p in O)delete Myobject[p];
for(var p in OP)delete Myobject.prototype[p];
```

Comment: Interesting idea, will try. And also - if they are non-enumerable, then it's already OK. I only care about the enumerable ones in the first place.